# Is there anyway to write 1 single rule to redirect multiple dynamic URLS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hey everyone I search around for this answer but could only find ways to redirect each URL individually.

My old site urls were like this:

```
www.domain.com/show_detail.php?item=item_description_of_various_lengths
```

new URLs are like this:

```
www.domain.com/shop/brands/titan/item_description_of_various_lengths/
```

Now I know how to redirect these on a 1 by 1 basis. I used the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^item=item_description_of_various_lengths$ [NC]

RewriteRule show_detail.php http://www.domain.com/product-category/paint-spraying/hvlp-fine-finish/item_description_of_various_lengths/? [R=301,L]
```

Which works great and all but after writing about 200 of these I'm just wondering if there is a way to redirect ALL pages starting with show_detail.php to my home page and call it a day. **Or even better 1 rule that will just redirect all of them to a search page which searches the "item_description_of_various_Lengths" phrase automatically.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex catpure group to get value of the Item dynmically

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^item=([^&]+)$ [NC]
```

And then replace **description_of_v_length** with **%1?** in the target url.

Comment: RewriteCode %{QUERY_STRING} ([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule show_detail.php http://www.jnequipment.com/shop/%1?       This caused an error  am I missing a $ at the end of the 2nd line or do I need a [R=301,L]

Comment: [R,L] is important if you want an external redirection, may I know what error you are getting?

Comment: upon review I had a syntax error and it was working I just can't spell.  But I have another question now the string returned is "item=Titan_Speeflo_Side_Striper_-_Line_Striper" right so that's great but how can I omit the first 5 character(item=) and convert all _ to +

Comment: First 5 chars are being appended because you did not use my code correctly, see the code in my answer again. you need to  use complete **^item=([^&]+)$**  not **^([^&]+)$**

Comment: Changing _ to + should be a new question, please. This is not related to your OP.